# SQL Server debugging

Tags: sql-server, debugging

I want to ask if there is a possibility to use some debugging option in the program?

Before when I worked with Visual Studio I can use the <kbd>F5</kbd> key to start debugging. Can I do it also with SQL?

When I'm trying to solve some query or see the steps of the program behind I want to see steps through the running process

Comment: In SSDT yes, in SSMS no (the debugger was removed in SSMS 18).

Comment: Even when it was included, setting it up and actually getting it to work typically required a good bit of hair pulling, even for a local server, let alone a remote one. It's less frustrating and more reliable to break your queries up into steps yourself and write them so that they're easily inspected in parts through the use of CTEs. The only thing you're missing then is parameter values when a stored procedure is executed, which you can get through either client-side logging or a profiler/extended events trace.

Answer (score 1):

By and large, the style of debugging where you walk through code, manually advancing execution line by line, with breakpoints and windows showing current variable contents, is a poor fit for database work. Done properly it means creating and holding locks as you go through your code, and depending on environment (none of us would ever do this on Production, of course) that could cause serious blocking problems. Also, viewing the contents of temp tables can be highly problematic.

As others have and probably will say, you are better off manually setting input values and running selected chunks of code at a time, with PRINT and SELECT statements showing what's going on at any given point. This can be slow, a bit awkward, and very effective.

Answer (score 0):

I used to print message all over the procedures with a format in this procedure. Also to prevent sending message to application. It checks whether it is production server or not. (using a setting table).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dba.Usp_Util_TraceLog
    @ProcId INT, @Message NVARCHAR(4000) = '', @Param0 NVARCHAR(255) = NULL, @Param1 NVARCHAR(255) = NULL, @Param2 NVARCHAR(255) = NULL, @Param3 NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (mon.fn_Setting_Get('is_production_envirement') = 1)
        RETURN;

    SET @Param0 = ISNULL(@Param0, '');
    SET @Param1 = ISNULL(@Param1, '');
    SET @Param2 = ISNULL(@Param2, '');
    SET @Param3 = ISNULL(@Param3, '');

    SET @Message = REPLACE(@Message, '{0}', @Param0);
    SET @Message = REPLACE(@Message, '{1}', @Param1);
    SET @Message = REPLACE(@Message, '{2}', @Param2);
    SET @Message = REPLACE(@Message, '{3}', @Param3);

    DECLARE @proc_name sysname;
    DECLARE @schema_name sysname;
    SELECT @proc_name = o.name, @schema_name = s.name
    FROM sys.objects AS o
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
    WHERE o.object_id = @ProcId;
    
    DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(4000)= CONCAT('[', @schema_name, '].[', @proc_name, ']: ', @Message)

    PRINT @msg;
END;
GO
```